# Procedure that does not UPDATE a table row

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have this procedure (don't bother too much to figure it out what it does, aim for comments named "Modify 1,2,3,4" )

```
/* PROCEDURE 1 : Post notification */
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS AddNotificationOnPosts;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AddNotificationOnPosts`(arg_from_user INT(11),arg_on_post_id INT(11),arg_in_group_id INT(11))
BEGIN
    DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE insert_result INT DEFAULT NULL;
    DECLARE user_id INT DEFAULT NULL;

    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE var_user_id INT DEFAULT NULL;
        DECLARE c1 CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT user_id 
        FROM user_rights 
        WHERE user_rights.right = 101 AND user_rights.group_id  = arg_in_group_id 
        ORDER BY user_id DESC;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = 1;

    IF(arg_from_user IS NULL OR arg_from_user = '')
    THEN
        SELECT "0" AS response;
    ELSEIF(arg_on_post_id IS NULL OR arg_on_post_id = '')
    THEN
        SELECT "0" AS response;
    ELSEIF(arg_in_group_id IS NULL OR arg_in_group_id = '')
    THEN
        SELECT "0" AS response;
    ELSE
        SELECT count(notification_id) FROM notifications_posts 
        WHERE 
        from_user = arg_from_user AND
        on_post_id = arg_on_post_id AND
        in_group_id = arg_in_group_id
        INTO num_rows;

        /* MODIFY 1*/
        UPDATE user_info SET notifications = 1 WHERE user_id = 145;
    END IF;

    IF num_rows = 0
    THEN
        INSERT INTO notifications_posts(from_user,on_post_id,in_group_id) VALUES(arg_from_user,arg_on_post_id,arg_in_group_id);
        SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO insert_result;

        /* MODIFY 2*/
        UPDATE user_info SET notifications = 1 WHERE user_id = 1;

        IF insert_result > 0 
        THEN

        /* MODIFY 3*/
        UPDATE user_info SET notifications = 1 WHERE user_id = 5;

            /* Increment the notifications for every user*/
            OPEN c1;
            read_loop: LOOP
                FETCH c1 INTO var_user_id;
                    IF done THEN
                        LEAVE read_loop;
                    ELSE
                        /* MODIFY 4*/
                        UPDATE user_info SET notifications = 1 WHERE user_id = 1;
                    END IF;
            END LOOP;
            CLOSE c1;

            SELECT "1" AS response;
        ELSE
            SELECT "0" AS response;
        END IF;

    ELSE
        SELECT "0" AS response;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

This works just fine, except the lines

```
 UPDATE user_info SET notifications = 1 WHERE user_id = 1;
```

won't work, but in simple plain SQL(phpmyadmin) this query is working fine. What is the problem?

What this script does? It helps me be able to post a notification to certain users, and when you post **something** in **group1** all users that have **right101** on that group must be notified like

```
 UPDATE user_info SET notifications = notifications  + 1 WHERE user_id = var_user_id;
```

using a cursor as a `FOR LOOP` like i used to have in PHP

What is wrong with this? Can't a procedure update data?!
Hope i made myself understandable.

Comment: Is this query INSERT INTO notifications_posts(from_user,on_post_id,in_group_id) VALUES(arg_from_user,arg_on_post_id,arg_in_group_id);
        SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO insert_result;
is running ?

Comment: i don't know, but the INSERT INTO works fine

Comment: MySQL ... but i don't believe that INSERT into is running, because no matter i put UPDATE, it never works ...

Comment: IS it possible that in the  IF(arg_from_user IS NULL OR arg_from_user = '') statement one of the condition is true? And the else not running? Because in this case the num_rows is NULL.

Comment: after running this the response is 1, and inserts that particular row, but updating is not executed noware, understood?

Answer (score 3):

Not to sound presumptuous but does the data allow you to get past the

```
IF num_rows = 0
```

As a tip though if you are running in SQL Management studio you can debug your sql with breakpoints like normal code. I suggest putting a breakpoint on that line and see if it actually gets hit at all.

Comment: first of all, what is a BRAKEPOINT, and second, should i use TRANSACTION ? Be aware that i'm using a CURSOR, so that may change a lot

Comment: A breakpoint is a stopping point in code. You can use it to stop code at a certain point and view the current state (e.g the values of all your variables and what methods are actually returning). SQL Server Management Studio allows you to do this with SQL code, you can see what the issue is. However, since you tagged this with MYSQL, I don't think it's relevant to you, so no need to worri :)

Comment: Its also tagged with SQL. If you are using SQL Management Studio and a SQL Database then you could put a breakpoint on a line of SQL that you want to check. Then by press the "play" button or F5 you can go into debug mode. This will allow you to step through your code line by line by pressing f10 (note you can step into a stored proc with this also). By pressing f5 again you will skip to the next breakpoint. By putting a breakpoint on your code you can check to see if that line of code is executed at all. Additionally you can "watch" variables and see the values that are being passed around.

Answer (score 1):

How about something along these lines?  I usually work in SQL Server, so I apologize if some of the syntax is off, but I threw in some comments, so I hope you get the gist.

```
/* PROCEDURE 1 : Post notification */ 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS AddNotificationOnPosts; 

DELIMITER $$ 
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `AddNotificationOnPosts`(arg_from_user INT(11), arg_on_post_id INT(11), arg_group_id INT(11)) 
BEGIN 

    -- sanity checks
    IF(arg_from_user IS NULL OR arg_from_user = '') 
    THEN 
        RETURN 0;
    ELSEIF(arg_on_post_id IS NULL OR arg_on_post_id <= 0) 
    THEN 
        RETURN 0;
    ELSEIF(arg_in_group_id IS NULL OR arg_in_group_id <= 0) 
    THEN 
        RETURN 0;
    END IF;

    BEGIN TRAN;

    -- insert if notification post does not exist
    IF NOT EXISTS
    ( 
        SELECT * 
        FROM notification_posts
        WHERE  
            from_user = arg_from_user AND 
            on_post_id = arg_on_post_id AND 
            in_group_id = arg_in_group_id 
    )               
    THEN

        INSERT INTO notifications_posts
        (
            from_user,
            on_post_id,
            in_group_id
        ) 
        VALUES
        (
            arg_from_user,
            arg_on_post_id,
            arg_in_group_id
        ); 
    END IF;


    -- update all users with 101 right

    UPDATE ui 
        SET notifications = notifications + 1
    FROM user_info ui
    JOIN user_rights ur on ur.user_id = ui.user_id
    WHERE ur.right = 101 and ur.group_id = arg_in_group_id

    COMMIT;
END $$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: use transactions? that is the idea? be aware that i'm using a cursor, and i don't know if this will work, but why a UPDATE does not work in a procedure?!?

Comment: My solution DOES use a transaction, and yes, it's a good idea.  Also, I removed the cursor, wasn't needed that I could see.  Not sure why you think your update wasn't working, but check out the proc I provided and see if that fits your needs.

Comment: i found a part of error, the user_id from `DECLARE user_id INT DEFAULT NULL;` and `UPDATE user_info SET notifications = 1 WHERE user_id = 1;` are making an ambiguity, and even when you change with `UPDATE user_info SET notifications = 12412 user_info.user_id = 1;` it won't work, so i must change the name of the variables, see?

Comment: @Empeus - You need to change more than just the var names, you need to also get rid of that cursor, use IF EXISTS instead of select count(*) into rowcount, dump all the extra vars, use transactions...

Comment: i imagine that cursor as being a `FOR LOOP` in PHP, get me? and with `SELECT ROW_COUNT() INTO insert_result;` i check if the query was done properly, thank you for advices

Comment: PHP and SQL are two different beasts. RDBMS can use JOIN logic in place of loops, where PHP cannot.

Comment: what? do you have an example of this, i'm curious :)

Comment: an example?? Are you kidding? did you see my answer?  It uses a `join` instead of a cursor and `if exists` instead of `count(*)`. What other examples are you wanting??

Comment: thank you, i solved my problem with this http://codepad.org/WxSdWfzY but i never worked with this method, good to know :)